# How to pass variables within controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hi I need to use a variable from the result scope of one controller to another controller. I can achieve this by using nested controller but in my case my controller 2 is not a child of controller 1. I somehow able to achieve my output with the following controller but still i want to know is this best practice if not how can i pass variables between various controllers.

```
 angular.module('test',[])
        .factory('PassParameter', PassParameter)
    function PassParameter(){
         var thisValue = {};
        return {
            getParameter: function () {
                return thisValue;
            },
            setParameter: function (setValue) {
                _.extend(thisValue, setValue);
            },
            removeParameter : function(value) {
                _.omit(thisValue, value);
            }
        };
    };
```

i Pass an object to setParameter function and get by its value from getParameter function.

Comment: Well I am currently using a setter / getter Factory like yours, besides I am using the Localstorage to save some data there, antoher Option would be to use $rootScope which is available in all Controllers but i wouldnt recommend that only for a few important variables

Comment: to do thing like that there the services. they are function that you can inject inside the controller, you pute settere and gettere inside that so you have that variable injected anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way that I'm passing info between controllers.
*Note that I'm using angular.copy so I won't lose reference, this way when "obj" is changed, you don't need to get it again.(works only on objects {})

```
angular.module('test').service('mySrv',
function () {
    var obj = {};

    this.getObj = function(){
        return obj;  
    };

    this.setObj = function(obj){
        obj = angular.copy(obj);
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes i can use angular.copy but if i try to pass variable for second time i will loose the first passed obj. where as in extend method even after i finished use of that object my obj still has its value stored. I have edited my code to remove used no more need values. but still i want to know if there is some better solution for it?